# Does Soraka's heal CD get reduced per champ when hitting with Starcall?

Tags: league-of-legends

Starcall says that hitting at least one champ will reduce the CD on Astral Blessing. Does it reduce by that percent only once per Starcall, or that percent * champs hit with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Starcall hits at least one enemy champion, Astral Blessing's cooldown is reduced by 5 / 6.25 / 7.5 / 8.75 / 10% of its base cooldown (after factoring in cooldown reduction).

You answered your own question yourself.

If it hits one or more champions, the cooldown is reduced.
So it is reduced only once per starcall.

Comment: The part I was unsure about was if it reduced the CD by 10% no matter how many champs you hit, or up to 50% if you hit all 5 enemy champs. Maybe I just worded it wrong but either way this answers it.